# How to keep the backslash in string?

Tags: java, string, backslash

Assume I have a string input as

```
String str = "xxx---xxx\\\'hi\'xx";
```

When I try to print the string, it becomes below because of the backslash:

```
xxx---xxx\'hi'xx
```

How can I make the output still as

```
xxx---xxx\\\'hi\'xx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the java compiler reads a literal string in a source file, it knows that the `backslash` is a special quoting character that is user to handle literaly the following character even if is was special, **including the backslash itself**.

So when you write `String s = 'a\\b';` you have defined `s` as the string containing 3 characters, `a`, `\`  and `b`.

So if you want a number or backslash characters in a string, just write twice this number in your source code.

Answer (score 0):

`String str = "xxx---xxx\\\\\\'hi\\'xx";` - will return your desired output

Answer (score 0):

Backslash on its own is an escape character. Read more about it [here](https://codegym.cc/groups/posts/escaping-characters-java).

In your case, you will have to print `"xxx---xxx\\\\\\'hi\\'xx"` to get the output as `"xxx---xxx\\\'hi\'xx"`. You may also find and replace all `"\"` with `"\\"` in your string for automation.